# Include newline character when reading with fscanf

Tags: c, file, scanf, stdio

How can I read a(n optional) newline character when reading a file word by word using `fscanf()`?

I know I could use `fgets()` + `strtok()`, but my program specifically requires `fscanf()`.

I've tried the following:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s%[\n]+", buf);
```

But it doesn't work whatsoever.

Comment: I think `fscanf("%s%[\n]+", &word)` works.  Not sure, it's been a while.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried and it didn't work. Thanks for commenting, I'll edit my question.

Comment: Skip whitespace before the word, not after. `fscanf(fp, " %s", buf);`

Comment: `%s` implicitly skips leading whitespace.

Comment: @melpomene Thank you. I'll fix it now.

Comment: Curious to know *why* you want to include a newline in the input, when it is more common to filter it.

Comment: Do you need to be able to read a line that is only `"\n"`?

Comment: @chux Nope. I need to read the last word of each line as "test\n".

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @melpomene It's part of a program I'm writing for university. I just need to figure out this problem and I can finally call it a day.

Comment: Suppose the last line does not *have* a `'\n'`?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: What is the maximum word length, including ones that might end with `'\n'`?

Comment: @chux 200 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consume and ignore a single newline character with this conversion format: `%*1[\n]`. It consumes at most one newline and discards it. Note that if you have multiple consecutive newlines, only the first one will be skipped. Note too that `fscanf()` will read an extra byte to verify whether it matches or not. This byte will be pushed back into the stream with `ungetc()` if it does not match.

If you used `%*[\n]`, `fscanf` would keep reading the stream until it gets a byte different from newline or reaches the end of file, which would cause surprising behavior when handling interactive input from the terminal.

Your code `fscanf(fp, "%s[\n]", buf);` causes undefined behavior because you do not provide a destination array for the newline characters. Furthermore, it has another flaw because you do not specify the maximum number of bytes to store into `buf`, causing undefined behavior on input with long words.

Try this:

```
    char buf[100];
    if (fscanf(" %99s%*1[\n]", buf) == 1) {
        printf("read a word: |%s|\n", buf);
    } else {
        printf("no more words\n");
    }
```

If you want to include the newline in the buffer, you will need to store it into a variable and add it by hand:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    for (;;) {
        char buf[100];
        char nl[2] = "";
        int n = fscanf(stdin, " %98s%1[\n]", buf, nl);
        if (n > 0) {
            strcat(buf, nl);
            printf("read a word: |%s|\n", buf);
        } else {
            printf("no more words\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
Hello word
  I     am   ready
```

Output:

```
read a word: |Hello|
read a word: |word
|
read a word: |I|
read a word: |am|
read a word: |ready|
no more words
```

Comment: Note:: `" " ` not needed in `" %99s%*1[\n]"`.  Further this will block until a non-white-space is entered.

Comment: I've tried your code and got the same problem. I should get something like "test\n" as the last word of a line, but I only get "test".

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you, but I have to read multiple lines and I don't exactly know when to add '\n', so that's why I need fscanf() to do it for me.

Comment: @user10480767: the code above will include the newline only if present just after the word. It will ignore and whitespace before the word, you can call it in a loop but other newlines will be ignored.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but it doesn't wanna work. I've also tried debugging and it doesn't even read the '\n'. What am I missing? I've copied your entire code D:

Comment: @user10480767 Its just you :p. The `FILE*` parameter to `fscanf()` is missing from the examples. You'll have to run the code in a loop to read the entire file.

Comment: Ok, I've adjusted my code and now it seems to work really well! Thank you!